# get parent frame height with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, frame

I want to get the height of parent frame with jQuery.

It's my orginal script

```
var iframeElement = parent.document.getElementById('FrmPatient'); 
iframeElement.style.height = 170;
```

I want to change this script to jQuery style. How to get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$("#FrmPatient", parent.document).css("height", 170);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('FrmPatient').parent().css('height', '170px');
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I found two ways:

one is

var theFrame = $("#FrmPatient", parent.document.body);
theFrame.height(30);

and the rest one is above answer of @spinon.